# Add custom type with zend framework in php?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I can't add new type with zend framework. I've tried this

```
$server = new Zend_Soap_Server('http://localhost/CycleProphet/amember/ws/index/wsdl');

$server->addComplexType('AMemberUser');

class AMemberUser
{
    public $UserId;
    public $FirstName;
    public $LastName;
}
```

Type has been added, but it is empty. I use this article http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.wsdl.html#zend.soap.wsdl.types.add_complex, but it isn't help me.

Comment: Why minus? I can provide any information if this need.

Comment: people should leave a comment when a down vote is made!!

Comment: I agree with Songo. Somone who down voted it should tell why, so author will know for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment I decided to rewrite my answer and provide you some solution with wsdl:

```
<?php

require_once('Zend/Soap/Client.php');
require_once('Zend/Soap/Server.php');
require_once('Zend/Soap/Wsdl.php');
require_once('Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover.php');

class SoapController extends AppController 
{    
    public function zendclientAction()
    {
        $_client = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://localhost/php5_testapp/soap/zendserver?wsdl');
        $_ret = $_client->addNumbers(3, 5);

        echo('<pre>');
        var_dump($_ret);
        echo('<pre>');
        die();
    }

    public function zendserverAction()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
            $_autod = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
            $_autod->setClass('MySoapServerClass');
            $_autod->handle();
        }
        else {
            $_server = new Zend_Soap_Server('http://localhost/php5_testapp/soap/zendserver?wsdl');
            $_server->setClass("MySoapServerClass");
            $_server->handle();
        }

        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * My Soap Server Class
 */
class MySoapServerClass {

    /**
     * This method adds two numbers
     * 
     * @param integer $a
     * @param integer $b
     * @return string
     */
    public function addNumbers($a, $b) {

        return 'Outcome is: ' . ($a + $b);
    }
}
```

Now you can add whatever class you want! But remember - your class should be well documented, because WSDL file is generated basing on this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, Carlos. Function addNumber return string, but I want add custom type and add its to wsdl description.

Comment: Hey Ilya, I rewrited my answer, as now I understand it better. Check this out.